# How may I copy a folder from one WSL subsystem to another WSL subsystem

Tags: directory, interop, wsl-2

I have two WSL subsystems (call the UA and UB), both Ubuntu but configured differently.
How may I copy a folder from UA to UB, preserving all the permissions and any other properties?

I have tried using PowerShell 7.4:

```
$sourcePath = "\\wsl$\UA\\root\\fooDir"
$destPath = "\\wsl$\UB\\root\\fooDir"

Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destPath -Recurse -Force -Include -UseBac
```

The command produces no errors but does not copy the files either.

Leaving off the `-Include -UseBac` copies the files but loses there permissions and attributes.

I could use `tar` to make a single file, copy, then expand, but I am looking for something more interop.